ROS 2 Camera_ros: Failed to Configure Streams on Raspberry Pi 5
I am working on a ROS 2 project using a Raspberry Pi 5 and an IMX708 camera module. The camera previously worked flawlessly with the camera_ros package, but after a system reset and updates, I am unable to configure the camera streams.
Setup Details:

Hardware: Raspberry Pi 5 + IMX708 Camera Module
OS: Ubuntu 24.04
ROS 2 Jazzy
Libraries: libcamera, v4l2, camera_ros

Errors:

Can't configure camera with invalid configuration
failed to configure streams
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'

Troubleshooting Steps:

Verified camera functionality using QCam (it works fine).
Tested supported resolutions and formats like 1640x1232-YUYV.
Reinstalled dependencies and reverted to previous versions of libcamera and camera_ros.

Questions:

Is there a known issue with camera_ros or libcamera on Raspberry Pi 5?
What debugging steps can I take to resolve these configuration issues?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
What I Tried:
Verifying Camera Functionality:
I tested the IMX708 camera module using QCam, and it works perfectly, confirming that the camera hardware is functioning and libcamera is operational outside of ROS 2.
Adjusting Parameters:
I used supported resolutions and formats, such as 1640x1232-YUYV, and modified parameters in camera_ros, including pixel_format, width, and height. Despite this, the camera_ros node fails with the same errors.
Reinstalling Dependencies:
I completely reinstalled the required dependencies for libcamera, v4l2, and camera_ros. I also reverted to older versions of these libraries to rule out potential compatibility issues introduced in recent updates.
Running Diagnostics:
I checked logs and error messages for both libcamera and camera_ros and noted the specific failures:
Can't configure camera with invalid configuration
failed to configure streams
Exception: std::runtime_error: failed to configure streams
System Reset:
I performed a system reset and re-applied the setup from scratch, but the issue persists.
What I Was Expecting:
The camera_ros node to configure the camera streams successfully and publish image data on ROS topics without requiring significant manual adjustments, as it did during my initial setup.
Consistent behavior across resets, as no changes were made to the hardware or base software configuration that previously worked.
